# jquery add link at the end of each paragraph

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of paragraphs like this:

```
<p class="text-box"><input name=""/></p>
<p class="text-box"><input name=""/></p>
<p class="text-box"><input name=""/></p>
<p class="text-box"><input name=""/></p>
<p class="text-box"><input name=""/></p>
...
<p class="text-box"><input name=""/></p>
```

I want to insert a link within each `<p></p>` using jQuery

The result should be something like this:

```
<p class="text-box"><input name=""/><a href='#' class='remove-box'>Remove</a></p>
<p class="text-box"><input name=""/><a href='#' class='remove-box'>Remove</a></p>
<p class="text-box"><input name=""/><a href='#' class='remove-box'>Remove</a></p>
<p class="text-box"><input name=""/><a href='#' class='remove-box'>Remove</a></p>
.....
<p class="text-box"><input name=""/><a href='#' class='remove-box'>Remove</a></p>
```

P.S.

I've done so far this:

```
var html = $("<a href='#' class='remove-box'>Remove</a>");

$('p.text-box:last').after(html);
```

Maybe I didn't explained it correct: the link should be inserted within every `<p></p>`

Comment: `var html = $("<a href='#' class='remove-box'>Remove</a>");

$('p.text-box:last').after(html);` or `Maybe I didn't explained it correct: the link should be inserted within every <p></p>`? So what exactly you want? One remove-link or remove-link in every `.text-box`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the append function:

```
$('.text-box').append("<a href='#' class='remove-box'>Remove</a>");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C9PzP/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( "<a href='#' class='remove-box'>Remove</a>" ).insertAfter( ".text-box input" );


 $( ".text-box" ).append( $( ".text-box" ) );
```

This  is only two solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p.text-box').find('input').after('<a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a>');
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7ULu/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$("p:last").append("<a href='#' class='remove-box'>Remove</a>");
```

Finds last `p` element and append there `a` element.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zv9B3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

read about `append` function http://api.jquery.com/append/

**started html :**

```
 <h2>Greetings</h2>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
    </div>
```

**js code :**

```
 $( ".inner" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

**result :**

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
<div class="inner">
Hello
<p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="inner">
Goodbye
<p>Test</p>
</div>
</div>
```

---

**your solution** : http://jsfiddle.net/j8nc2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need:

```
var html = "<a href='#' class='remove-box'>Remove</a>";
$('p.text-box').append(html);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/tr6wH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right: you want to *append* a *link* at the end of each *p*

```
var $linkElement = $('<a>', {
    href: '#',
    class: 'remove-box'
});
$('p').append( $linkElement );
```

Please read the docs before asking: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element
>   in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, try this:

```
$('p.text-box').append("<a href='#' class='remove-box'>Remove</a>");
```

Fiddle is [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/cWUZE/)